# Problema em verificação com IF em C

Tags: c

Preciso informar se a pessoa está aprovada ou reprovada. Para o conceito D e frequência maior que 75 está aparecendo aprovado porém era para ser reprovado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float frequencia;
    char nome[180],conceito[180];
    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    scanf("%s",&nome);     
    printf ("\n Digite seu conceito final com letra MAIUSCULA:");
    scanf ("%s",&conceito);
    printf ("\n Digite o valor da sua frequencia:");
    scanf ("%f",&frequencia);       
    printf ("\n Nome do aluno:%s",nome);
    printf ("\n O valor da sua frequencia e %f",frequencia);


    if(conceito=="C" || frequencia>=75){
        printf ("\n Voce esta aprovado");
    }
    else
        printf ("\n Voce esta reprovado");
    getch ();
    return 1 ;

    if(conceito=="B" || frequencia>=75){
        printf ("\n Voce esta aprovado");
    }
    else
        printf ("\n Voce esta reprovado");
    getch ();
    return 1 ;

    if(conceito=="A" || frequencia>=75){
        printf ("\n Voce esta aprovado");
    }
    else
        printf ("\n Voce esta reprovado");
    getch ();
    return 1 ;

    if(conceito=="D" && frequencia >=75){
        printf ("\n Voce esta reprovado");
    }
    else
        printf("\n Voce esta reprovado");
    getch ();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, isso não existe em C:

```
using namespace std;
```

Em segundo lugar, se "conceito" é só uma letra, porque está declarado com 180 caracteres ???

```
char nome[180], conceito[180];
```

Em terceiro lugar, a comparação de strings está errada, deveria ser

```
if (conceito[0] == 'C')
```

ou então

```
if (strncmp(conceito, "C", 1) == 0)
```

Em quarto lugar o programa está fazendo apenas a primeira comparação com "C",  por causa do comando "return" logo em seguida o programa termina sem fazer as outras comparações.

Em quinto lugar seria aconselhável usar "getchar" que é do padrão C, ao invés de "getch" que é específico do Microsoft C.

a comparação poderia ser feita de uma vez só, assim

```
if ((conceito[0] == 'A' || conceito[0] == 'B' || conceito[0] == 'C')
     && (frequencia >= 75))
  printf("\nVoce esta' aprovado");
else
  printf("\nVoce esta' reprovado");

getchar();
return 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro problema é que você está usando o operador `||` (OR) nas verificações de `if`. Quando a execução chega em `if(conceito=="C" || frequencia>=75)` ele verifica se o conceito é igual a C **OU** se a frequência é maior ou igual a 75, se qualquer um desses casos der certo então ele entrará nessa verificação.

Logo, quando o conceito for D e a frequencia for maior ou igual a 75 ele entrará em todos os `if`s os pois você está sempre usando o operador `||`. Para solucionar basta trocar os operadores de `||` (OR) para `&&` (AND), assim ele só dará verdadeiro em `if(conceito=="C" || frequencia>=75)` caso o conceito seja igual a C **E** a frequência maior ou igual a 75.

O segundo problema é a forma de comparação de strings, você está usando o operador `==` para comparar strings porém isto não funciona corretamente, sugiro que utilize a função `strcmp()` da lib `string.h`.

Outro ponto que destaco no seu código é que você está repetindo muitos `if`s, do modo que está fazendo ele irá verificar cada `if` e executar o seu `else` e assim aperecerá diversas mensagens de *"Voce esta reprovado."*, sugiro que edite usando `else if` entre suas validações.

Além disto, algo que percebi é que você está executando `getch ();` e `return 1 ;` após cada um dos `if`s porém não há necessidade disto bastando executar apenas quando as verificações forem encerradas já que ele só entrará em um `if`.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
if(strcmp(conceito,"C") == 0 && frequencia >= 75) {
    printf ("\n Voce esta aprovado");
} else if (strcmp(conceito,"B") == 0 && frequencia >= 75) {
    printf ("\n Voce esta aprovado");
} else if (strcmp(conceito,"A") == 0 && frequencia >= 75) {
    printf ("\n Voce esta aprovado");
} else if(strcmp(conceito,"D") == 0 && frequencia >=75) {
    printf ("\n Voce esta reprovado");
} else printf("\n Voce esta reprovado");

getch ();
```

Comment: Seguinte está ocorrendo mesmo erro comigo, pedi ajuda de uns amigos eles tentaram trocar, porém ficou igual o teu e quando dava D e >=75 o meu saia errado, mas no de vocês o de mostra A >=75 Reprovado, isso com A,B e C sendo que era para aparecer aprovado.
(Mais especificamente o único erro do meu você corrigiu mas deu erro nos outros)

Comment: A verificação de strings estava sendo de forma incorreta, já corrigi